# Tkinter grid cells displaying on top of each other

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and I'm trying to make a few windows using the grid() method.

However, I'm always struggling to understand which cell will show above the other when resizing the window to a very small one.
Sometimes the last-added one will be on top, sometimes not (my last example is a separator going on top of a frame containing labels even though I declared the separator first).

Could anyone explain to me how these 'levels' work? and how I can set which one should 'disappear' behind the other in case the user decides to resize the window to make it small?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is links: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Tkinter, stacking order of widgets is determined by the order in which they are added to their parent widget.
- When widgets are added to a grid layout using the `grid()` method, the stacking order is still determined by the order in which they are added, but it's also influenced by the row and column indices specified in the grid layout.
- However, when resizing the window to a very small size, widgets may overlap or appear on top of each other depending on their geometry management and resizing properties.
- To control the stacking order, you can use the `lift()` and `lower()` methods of the widget. These methods allow you to raise a widget to the top of the stacking order (lift()) or lower it to the bottom (lower()).